# About cascode tuned circuits

Tags: amplifier, rf

In the following 2-stage cascode tuning amplifier, assuming that both tuned circuits have the same resonant frequency. Is the output voltage 90 degrees "delayed" with respect to the input (i.e. vo = -j(constant)*vi) at the resonant frequency?

[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1):

At resonance, a parallel tuned LC produces zero phase shift hence, with two parallel tuned circuits separated by a buffer, the effect is the same i.e. zero phase shift apart from the inversion due to the buffer being an inverter.

Parallel LC filter [on-line calculator](http://stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20BPF/RCL%20BPF.html?LMCL=Urnond): -

[image]

If the LC were a low-pass resonant circuit then there would be two lots of 90 degrees phase shift for the whole circuit and a further 180 degrees due to the inversion. Same for a high-pass LC circuit.